# A double-sum identity

Tags: calculus

Let $a_k$ be a sequence. Now prove that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{j+1}} \sum_{k=0}^{j}(-1)^k\binom{j}{k}a_{k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}a_{k}\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{j+1}} \binom{j}{k}.$$

I have tried but I can't. I know the identity
$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^{n}$.

Comment: You are summing over the set of couples $\{(k,j): 0\leq k\leq j\leq n-1\}$.

Comment: How does this prove the above statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the two given double sums, we are summing over the same set of couples $$S_n:=\{(j,k)\in\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: 0\leq k\leq j\leq n-1\}.$$ 
Hence for ANY double sequence $(A(j,k))_{j,k}$,
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{j} A(j,k)=\sum_{(j,k)\in S_n}A(j,k)=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} A(j,k).$$